# how can I use the JSON token Response returned by an endpoint to another .js file in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Ok, so I have a `Login.js` which has the `onSubmit` function which redirects the page to `UploadScreen.js`:

Login.js:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {

  const errors = this.validate(this.state);
  this.setState({ errors });
  e.preventDefault();
  var apiBaseUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/login";
  var self = this;
  var payload={
      "email":this.state.email,
      "password":this.state.password
  }
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    withCredentials: false
  }

  axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status == 200){
        browserHistory.push('/upload');
        self.setState({
          redirect_to_upload : true
        }) 
    }
    else if(response.status == 204){
        console.log("Username password do not match");
        alert("username password do not match")
    }
    else{
        console.log("Username does not exists");
        alert("Username does not exist");
    }
})
.catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
});
}
```

this is the response I get 
[image]

so now, in the UploadScreen.js there is another endpoint I am calling, the endpoint http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/materials (GET) but I cannot access it because I need a token, and that token is provided with the response I got from earlier as highlighted.

In postman, it's like this
[image]
I won't be able to get anything if I don't provide the token

so my 1st question is:

> How can I add the token I got from the onSubmit function earlier that is located in Login.js to this GET request I want to send now? (I am in UploadScreen.js)

and my second question is:

> what if I want to get the uuid on that response (as highlighted) and make it the value of a Form.Input for example, and that form input is located on a different js file?

```
class UploadScreen extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
          profile_id: '',
          errors: {}
        }
       }

   <Form.Input
     type='text'
     name='profile_id'
     value={} <<< what should I do, to be able to make the value to the uuid(in response, and make it appear as the placeholder of the input
```

I apologize for my english and I hope someone can help me with a specific answer because I am new to React Programming. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it in localStorage and then set it as default headers so later you can use it on server to verify if the user is authenticated or not for that particular request.

```
axios.post(apiBaseUrl, payload, config)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    if(response.status == 200){
        localStorage.setItem('jwt',res.data.token);//add this
        setHeader(res.data.token);// add this
        browserHistory.push('/upload');
        self.setState({
          redirect_to_upload : true
        }) 
    }
```

you **setHeader.js**

```
import axios from 'axios'
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'

export default function setAuthToken(token){

    if(token){
        localStorage.setItem('jwt',token)
        axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`
    }
    else{
        delete axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization']
    }
}
```

Now on server like express.js you can

```
app.post('baseUrl',function(req,res){
  var header = req.headers['authorization']
  if(header){
   var token = header.split(' ')[1]
   //verify your jwt here
   if(userIsAllowed){
     //process
     res.send('hello')
    }else{
      res.status(404).send()
    }
  }
})
```

Now only problem left is when user refresh the page then headers will be reset to handle that you can (in you **index.js** where all routes are imported and rendered (`render<Router>....</Router>,document.getElementById('root')`)

```
....
 if(localStorage.getItem('jwt')){
   setToken('token',localStorage.getItem('jwt'))
 }
....
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the amount of information you provided, here is what I understood.

You call an api and navigate to upload screen, but you need some data from the api which should already be present on the upload screen so that you can perform further action.

So, you'll be required to pass extra parameters to the screen you are navigating to. Assuming you are using `react-router` ( and if you aren't, I'll recommend it, it makes routing life easy)

Now, assuming you have the `history` object already in scope, you can do -

```
this.props.history.push({pathname:'/upload', token: response.data.current_user.uuid})
```

And now when you `console.log(this.props.location.token)` you can find the value which you can use

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can always setState your token (first you should create an empty state for token) and then pass it down as a props to  another component.

And you can access your token via

```
console.log(response.data.current_user.token)
```